# How to move the element in div to first position after clicking to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var position = $("#navigationAccount").position();
document.getElementById('navigationMobile').scrollLeft += position.left;
```

Comment: A view of the HTML DOM might make answering possible.

Answer (score 1):

`position` does not fit your need, see  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_position
`position` is used to get the position of the target element.

Instead you need to use something like `prependTo`.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $(".move").prependTo("#wrapper")
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p class="move">move</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: on horizontal navbar containing inner six div and if we applied slick slider to that and during sliding if we click it(any div out of 6),it  will move to first position that is towards left

Answer (score 1):

You can easily shift children around using the [`$.fn.siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [`$.fn.insertBefore`](https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) functions.

The following jQuery plugin will allow you to move a child to the front of its siblings.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.shiftChild = function($target) {
    let $first = this.siblings().first();
    if ($target.get(0) !== $first.get(0)) {
      $target.insertBefore($first);
    }
    return this;
  }
})(jQuery);


$('.nav-menu').on('click', (e) => {
  $('.nav-menu').shiftChild($(e.target));
});
```

```css
#nav {
  background: #aaa;
  padding: 2px;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 2px 2px;
}

.nav-menu:first-child {
  background: #fff;
}

.nav-menu:not(:first-child) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav"><!--
  --><div class="nav-menu" id="nav-account">Account</div><!--
  --><div class="nav-menu" id="nav-mobile">Mobile</div><!--
  --><div class="nav-menu" id="nav-help">Help</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if we apply slick slider to it for mobile view then